# How to display a html page inside another html page div without using jquery

Tags: html, css

There are two html pages,if  clicked on a particular image in 1st page it will go to 2nd html page.
If clicked anywhere on 2nd html page it should come back to 1st page and display the 2nd page entirely in one of the div in 1st page

```
1st html  page :
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
                <title>Insert title here</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scripts.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/common.js"></script>
    
                </head>
                <body class="wt-bg" onload="initPr()">
                    <table class="header">
                        <tr>
                            <td id="branding2">
                                <div>
                                    <img src="images/slogo.png">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td id="header-recent">
                                <div>
                                    <a href=""><img class="topbar-icon" alt="Recent" src="images/nav_re.png"></a> <a
                                        href=""><img class="topbar-icon" alt="Gift" src="images/nav_gt.png"></a> <a href=""><img
                                        class="topbar-icon" alt="New" src="images/nav_new.png"></a>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="header-uscart">
                                <div>
                                    Hello <label id="username"></label> 
                                    <a onclick="openH()"><img class="topbar-icon" alt="Home" src="images/nav_ho.png"></a> 
                                    <a onclick="openUsDe()"><img class="topbar-icon" alt="Account" src="images/nav_act.png"></a> 
                                    <a onclick="openPre()"><img class="topbar-icon" alt="Settings" src="images/nav_pref.png"></a> 
                                    <a onclick="openCt()"><img class="topbar-icon" alt="Cart" src="images/nav_shcart.png"></a>
                                    <a onclick="openWce()"><img class="topbar-icon" alt="Logout" src="images/nav_custcare.png"></a>
                                </div>
    
    
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
    
                    <table class="main" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="left-bar top">
                                <div id="left-scroll">
                                    <div class="category-title">Category</div>
                                    <ul id="cat-list" class="category-list">
                                         <li class="category-title">Category</li>
                                        <li class="category-name"><a onclick="openCategory('toys')" class="no-underline">Kids
                                            toys</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-name"><a onclick="openCategory('mobile')" class="no-underline">Mobile</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-name"><a onclick="openCategory('tv')" class="no-underline">Television</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-name"><a onclick="openCategory('clothing')" class="no-underline">Clothing</a></li>
                                        <li class="category-name"><a onclick="openCategory('watches')" class="no-underline">Watches</a></li> 
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="top">
                                <div id="item-content">
                                    <div class="div-home">
                                        <marquee scrollamount="2">
                                            <div class="home-subtitle">Favorite Brand Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                                Favorite Brand Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                                Favorite Brand Store&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </div>
                                        </marquee>
                                        <div class="hscrollview">
                                            <img class="small-icon" src="images/le_small.png" onclick="openItem()">
                                            <img class="small-icon" src="images/sams_small.png">
                                            <img class="small-icon" src="images/gucci_small.png">
                                            <img class="small-icon" src="images/se_small.png">
                                            <img class="small-icon" src="images/dis_small.png">
                                            <img class="small-icon" src="images/leo_small.png">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="div-home">
                                        <marquee scrollamount="2">
                                            <div class="home-subtitle">Offers &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                                Offers&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                                            </div>
                                        </marquee>
                                        <div class="hscrollview">
                                            <div class="excl-offer">
                                                RemoteControlled Toys<br>
                                                <img class="small-icon" src="images/nav_side_ad2.png"> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="excl-offer">
                                                Trousers<br>
                                                <img class="small-icon" src="images/nav_side_ad4.png"> 
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="excl-offer">
                                                Watches<br>
                                                <img class="small-icon" src="images/nav_side_ad1.png">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="excl-offer">
                                                Phones<br>
                                                <img class="small-icon" src="images/nav_side_ad5.png">
                                            </div>
    
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
    
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="right-bar left-border top">
                                <div id="right-scroll">
                                    <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding-left: 0px">
                                        <li><img class="small-icon" src="images/naspeoffer.png">
                                        <li><img class="small-icon" src="images/ntoy.png">
                                        <li><img class="small-icon" src="images/mob.png">
                                        <li><img class="small-icon" src="images/tel.png">
                                        <li><img class="small-icon" src="images/clot.png">
                                        <li><img class="small-icon" src="images/wat.png">
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
    
                    <div id="product-details">
                        <div style="display: table-row;">
                            <div class="inline-block">
                                <img id="product_image" src="" width="150px" height="150px">
                            </div>
                            <div class="inline-block top" style="height: 150px; border: 1px solid green;">
                                <input type="hidden" id="pid" value="0"> <label id="product_name" class="bold font4"></label><br>
                                <label id="product_desc"></label><br> <label id="product_cost"></label>
                                <button class="roundbutton no-border button-font" onclick="adToCa(1)">BUY</button>
                            </div>
    
                            <table class="match-parent">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="left">
                                        <button class="roundbutton no-border button-font" onclick="opHome()">Continue
                                            Shopping</button>
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="right">
                                        <button class="roundbutton no-border button-font" onclick="adToCa(0)">Add to
                                            Shopping Cart</button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </body>
                </html>
```

Need to display the below 2nd html page within the  in 1st html page.

2nd html page :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
                <html>
                <head>
                <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
                <title>Insert title here</title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/styles.css" type="text/css" />
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/scripts.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/common.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.touchSwipe.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div id="initial-div" class="full-banner">
                        <div class="Item-header">
                            <img src="images/aa.png" style="margin-right: 50px;">
                            <label class="item-link1" onclick="showItemByGen('bbb','men')">Men</label>
                            <label class="item-link1" onclick="showItemByGen('ccc','women')">Women</label>
                            <label class="item-link1" onclick="showItemByGen('ddd','shoe')">Shoes</label>       
                        </div>
    
                        <div id="item-content">
                            <img id="image-current" src="images/item1.png"  onclick="openItemInFirstPage()"
                                style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block;> 
                             <div id="ITemTouch">
                                <div id="images">
                                    <img src="images/itemimg1.png">
                                    <img src="images/itemimg2.png">
                                    <img src="images/itemimg3.png">
                                </div>
                             </div>
                       </div>
                </div>
    
Clicked the image with id="image-current" in 2nd page : onclick="openItemInFirstPage() which takes to 1st page , also it takes the 2nd page html in a variable and appends it to 1st page div as below
    
    openItemInFirstPage = function(){
                SysJump.go("shop_home.html");
                $('#item-content').empty();
        var brand = 'aaa';
        var gender = 'women';
    
                var levisitem = '<div id="initial-div" class="full-banner"> ' 
                            + '<div class="Item-header"> '
                            + ' <img src="images/aa.png" style="margin-right: 50px;"> '
                            + ' <label class="item-link1" onclick="showItemByGen('bbb','men')">Men</label> '
                            + ' <label class="item-link1" 'onclick="showItemByGen('ccc','women')">Women</label> '
                            + ' <label class="item-link1" onclick="showItemByGen('ddd','shoe')">Shoes</label> '     
                            + '</div> '
    
                            + '<div id="item-content"> '
                            + '<img id="image-current" src="images/item1.png"  onclick="openItemInFirstPage()"
                                style="max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%; margin: auto; display: block;> '
                                + ' <div id="ITemTouch"> '
                                + ' <div id="images"> '
                                + ' <img src="images/itemimg1.png"> '
                                + ' <img src="images/itemimg2.png"> ' 
                                + ' <img src="images/itemimg3.png"> '
                                + ' </div> '
                                + ' </div> '
                          + ' </div> '
                   + ' </div>'
                alert(item);
                $('#item-content').append(item);
    }
```

But I am not getting the 2nd page in the div.  is not working if I add it in var item. Why is it so?

my css are :

```css
  .brand-header {
     display: table-row;
     border: 1px solid red;
     background: black;
     width: 100%;
    }
    
    .full-banner {
     border: 1px solid red;
     background: black;
     width: 100%;
     position: absolute;
    }
    
    .brand-link1 {
     display: table-cell;
     color: white;
     font-family: calibri;
     font-size: 25px;
     width: 100px;
     text-align: center;
     vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    .small-icon {
     width: 120px;
     height: 120px;
     margin-left: 10px;
     margin-right: 10px;
     padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
```

Comment: You're clearly using jQuery, why this title ? Also, please narrow down the problem and please create a jsFiddle. We definitely don't need your CSS while more javascript code might be of interest. I don't see any AJAX call for example...

Comment: Your JS code is breaking which is evident from the code block highlighting

Comment: Displayin a webpage inside a webpage can be achieved using an iframe.

Comment: I gave the css because when i am trying to display the the 2nd page inside the div in another page it is exceeding that div.Thought will get some points regarding that as well

Answer (score 0):

u can use iframe for this

inside your first page use

```
<iframe style="width:200px;height:200px" src="you 2nd page url"></iframe>
```

Comment: will it display inside a particular div?

Comment: yes you can add this code in any div and it will show u